# Does Dispel Magic work on Magic Circle Against Evil?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

Can *magic circle against evil* be dispelled by a simple *dispel magic*? If so, would the caster have to target an area or a specific target?

Comment: It might be useful to explain why you think *dispel magic* might not have worked against *magic circle against evil*; this isn't really a special case. Whatever got you thinking it might be a special case might be something we could expand on and address.

Comment: @KRyan If I had to speculate, it was probably a (calling) spell targeted against a creature with at-will *dispel magic*. But I'm sure you figured much the same.

Answer (score 8):

Yes.

Dispel Magic ends ongoing spells. Magic Circle Against Evil is an ongoing spell with no particular protections against dispelling. Therefore, it can be ended with Dispel Magic.

As for the targeting, MSAE targets a specific creature with a range of touch, and thereafter emanates from that targeted creature. Therefore that creature is what you would need to target with Dispel Magic. Targeting them directly with the single-target usage of Dispel Magic and catching them within the area of the AoE usage both work, subject to the respective limitations built into those usages of Dispel Magic.